# How to combine multiple formulas in 1 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am trying to combine the below two formulas in one cell, but no luck so far.

Both formulas work OK on their own, but I can not figure out how to combine them together to produce the result in same cell.

```
=IF(AND(C18>0, C6>J11), J11, C6) 

=IF(AND(C17<K5, C6>J10), J10, C6)
```

Comment: When you say combine which has priority?  Or do you want the output of both in one cell?

Comment: For your vocabulary, add "nested if statement" or "nested logical statement".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest functions inside each other, I think this is the one you need:

`=IF(AND(C18>0, C6>J11), J11, IF(AND(C17 <K5, C6>J10), J10, C6))`

Comment: Wow, it worked perfect. I see where I was going wrong. Than you very much for your help.

Comment: @GovVek Please don't forget to click in the Check Mark to mark it as accepted answer. Welcome to SuperUser!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to combine multiple formulas, but for a different purpose:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","e"),"oo","o")
```

It also works in Google Sheets.

[image]